# Can not unlock my WD passport

Tags: external-hdd

I can not get this sucker to to work, this is the message I get

```
Archive:  /media/WD Unlocker/WD Drive Unlock.exe
[/media/WD Unlocker/WD Drive Unlock.exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  /media/WD Unlocker/WD Drive Unlock.exe may be a plain executable, not an archive
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /media/WD Unlocker/WD Drive Unlock.exe or
          /media/WD Unlocker/WD Drive Unlock.exe.zip, and cannot find /media/WD Unlocker/WD Drive Unlock.exe.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: That file needs to be run on windows...

Comment: Close-voter(s): This is not off-topic because it's not a question about Windows, the file just happens to be a Windows program. Answers (like [minerz029's](http://askubuntu.com/a/344993/22949)) can explain this and offer alternatives.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/116548/47291

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to extract a **Microsoft Windows** `.exe` file with the `zip` utility, this will not work (it's not a `zip` file) and you will not be able to run this program in Ubuntu without [wine [image: Install wine]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine) or similar (it still *may* not work with wine).

If you haven't got any important files on that drive, just format it then use [truecrypt [image: Install truecrypt]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/truecrypt), which will also allow you to password protect and encrypt your drive with the advantage of being usable on Windows, Mac OS *and* Linux (Ubuntu).