# External Hard Drive Not Detected on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, external-hdd

My external hard drive, which was working perfectly fine a couple days ago, is not being detected.

There's no reason to suspect that it's broken as I have not really touched it. The HDD is connected via USB3 and I'm using Unity with Ubuntu 14.04. I recently installed Ubuntu on a new hard drive and have all my old Windows files on the external HDD. I've tried `fdisk`, Ubuntu's Disks utility, as well as a few other things in the terminal and nothing seems to even detect that it's connected. Can anyone assist with this? Thank you very much.

Edit: Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 4971:1013 SimpleTech 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:288a Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

And no, I have a completely new hard drive installed with a new OS so it is not a kernel upgrade.

Comment: Did you recently undergo a kernel upgrade?

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116478/wd-external-hard-drive-not-detected?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

When I get you right you are running a new installed Ubuntu on your internal hardrive and you have Problems to mount your (unchanged) external hardrive where you store your Windows files. Which filesystem do you use on the external hardrive and do you have several partitions.

I experienced some troubles with external hardrives when not cleanly unmounted at other computers or OS. Especially when hardrive was formatted with NTFS. If so try to mount partition at another computer (windows) and umount cleanly. This did solve my problems in most of the cases.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what partitions exist on the external hard drive - It's just a 3TB Hitachi HDD that I've used for a couple years now. I'm positive it will work on a windows OS.

Comment: Then please try to mount the disk in Windows and remove it safely. Then retry to mount it with ubuntu.